# Slash "/" in bash

Tags: command-line, paths

I'm learning bash language and I have a question:
Which is the difference between `/directory` and `directory/`. Because sometimes when I try:

```
cd Home/directory
```

I have the error

```
No such file etc etc..
```

Then I try some possibility like `/home/directory`, or `/home/directory/` and others...
 Thanks.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive so Home is going to be wrong most of the times (it will work if you made it yourself ;) ) And due get used to hitting TAB for auto-completion ;)

Comment: This has little to do with bash. Take a (good) look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-system.htm and around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is the very top of your filesystem.

If you type `cd /home/directory`, you can do that from anywhere, because it is the full path.

If you type `cd home/directory`, that will only work if you are in location `/`, similarly, if you are in `/home`, you could type `cd directory`, but not `cd /directory` (because that doesn't exist, it's either `/home/directory`, or just `directory` from `/home`)

You can always add a trailing slash, that does not make any difference, it's the first one that is important.